# How to get the ancestor node from this XML document?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml document, say of the format :

```
<DynamicReport>
    <DynamicReportDefId>501</DynamicReportDefId>
    <DynamicReportDefName>Test report</DynamicReportDefName>
    <DynamicReportDefSource>Live</DynamicReportDefSource>
    <IsPrivate>false</IsPrivate>
    <showSummaryRowsOnly>false</showSummaryRowsOnly>
    <Limit>false</Limit>
    <LimitRows/>
    <InvUserId/>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Category/>
    <Columns class="array">
        <Column>
            <TableName>vwdynfirms</TableName>
            <ColumnName>firmlongname</ColumnName>
            <FormattingInfo>
                <Header>
                    <DisplayName>Firm Long Name</DisplayName>
                    <FontInfo>
                        <Font/>
                        <FontSize/>
                        <IsBold/>
                        <IsItalic/>
                        <IsUnderline/>
                        <TextColor/>
                        <BackgroundColor/>
                    </FontInfo>
                    <AlignmentInfo>
                        <HorizontalAlignment/>
                        <VerticalAlignment/>
                    </AlignmentInfo>
                    <BorderInfo>
                        <BorderLeft/>
                        <BorderRight/>
                        <BorderTop/>
                        <BorderBottom/>
                    </BorderInfo>
                </Header>
                <Detail>
                    <FontInfo>
                        <Font/>
                        <FontSize/>
                        <IsBold/>
                        <IsItalic/>
                        <IsUnderline/>
                        <TextColor/>
                        <BackgroundColor/>
                    </FontInfo>
                    <AlignmentInfo>
                        <HorizontalAlignment/>
                        <VerticalAlignment/>
                    </AlignmentInfo>
                    <BorderInfo>
                        <BorderLeft/>
                        <BorderRight/>
                        <BorderTop/>
                        <BorderBottom/>
                    </BorderInfo>
                    <DisplayPattern/>
                </Detail>
            </FormattingInfo>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <TableName>vwdynfirms</TableName>
            <ColumnName>firmname</ColumnName>
            <FormattingInfo>
                <Header>
                    <DisplayName>Firm Name</DisplayName>
                    <FontInfo>
                        <Font>Calibri</Font>
                        <FontSize>14</FontSize>
                        <IsBold>true</IsBold>
                        <IsItalic/>
                        <IsUnderline/>
                        <TextColor>#FF0080</TextColor>
                        <BackgroundColor>#FFFFFF</BackgroundColor>
                    </FontInfo>
                    <AlignmentInfo>
                        <HorizontalAlignment>left</HorizontalAlignment>
                        <VerticalAlignment>bottom</VerticalAlignment>
                    </AlignmentInfo>
                    <BorderInfo>
                        <BorderLeft/>
                        <BorderRight/>
                        <BorderTop/>
                        <BorderBottom>true</BorderBottom>
                    </BorderInfo>
                </Header>
                <Detail>
                    <FontInfo>
                        <Font/>
                        <FontSize/>
                        <IsBold/>
                        <IsItalic/>
                        <IsUnderline/>
                        <TextColor/>
                        <BackgroundColor/>
                    </FontInfo>
                    <AlignmentInfo>
                        <HorizontalAlignment/>
                        <VerticalAlignment/>
                    </AlignmentInfo>
                    <BorderInfo>
                        <BorderLeft/>
                        <BorderRight/>
                        <BorderTop/>
                        <BorderBottom/>
                    </BorderInfo>
                    <DisplayPattern/>
                </Detail>
            </FormattingInfo>
        </Column>
    </Columns>
</DynamicReport>
```

From this xml document, I want to get the `TextColor` and the `BackgroundColor` for a particular `Column` and then store them in a map. I am expecting the map to be of the format `Map<String>, List<String>`
where the key is the `ColumnName` and the list of strings would be the two colors (`TextColor` and the `BackgroundColor`) as the values for the column in the map for now.

I have written the code, wherein I am not returning anything until I am able to get the column name by traversing back :

```
    //Getting the column from the colors for all the columns
    public static void getColors(Document doc)
    {
        String expressionGroupedCol = "/DynamicReport/Columns/Column/FormattingInfo/Header/FontInfo";
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        try {
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expressionGroupedCol).evaluate(
                    doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String strTextColor = eElement.getElementsByTagName("TextColor").item(0).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println(strTextColor);
                    String strBackgroundColor = eElement.getElementsByTagName("BackgroundColor").item(0).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println(strBackgroundColor);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am able to get the text color and background color. But I don't have a clue as to how to traverse back and get the corresponding column name and add that to the map. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about making a document scanner and loading the xml and creating a data model? XPath is great for querying xml to get to a place in the document, but it may not be the best tool for what you are trying to accomplish. Though I'm sure there are those who would disagree and hopefully they have a quick answer for you :)

Comment: Do you have to look for ColumnName as a parent element?  I think it would be cleaner to pass multiple, short XPath expressions to the same `XPath` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn’t what you asked for, I think you would be better off using an XPath to locate each `<Column>` element, then reusing your `XPath` instance to locate the data relative to it:

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> getColors(Document doc) {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    try {
        NodeList columns = (NodeList)
            xpath.evaluate("/DynamicReport/Columns/Column", doc,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);

        int numColumns = columns.getLength();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(numColumns);

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            Node column = columns.item(i);

            String columnName = xpath.evaluate("ColumnName", column);

            Node fontInfo = (Node) xpath.evaluate(
                "FormattingInfo/Header/FontInfo", column,
                    XPathConstants.NODE);

            String textColor =
                xpath.evaluate("TextColor", fontInfo);
            String backgroundColor =
                xpath.evaluate("BackgroundColor", fontInfo);

            map.put(columnName, Arrays.asList(textColor, backgroundColor));
        }

        return map;
    } catch (XPathException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

If you don’t pass an XPathConstants constant to `XPath.evaluate`, the text content of the matching node is returned, which turns out to be exactly what you want for obtaining your Strings.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was not aware that xPath.evaluate() function would give me the value right away. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind cheesing it :)

```
Element column = (Element)(eElement.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode());
```

Comment: If in the future the document hierarchy is changed by adding or removing ancestors of the context node, this code will stop producing the correct result. On the other side, evaluating this XPath expression will not be affected: `ancestor::Column[1]/ColumnName` .I will not be downvoting, am just commenting :)

Comment: Agreed :) I don't recommend cheesing it, but if it was time-sensitive, release the Cheddar and wait for an XSL guy to come in and say "Whoah!"

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to get the text color and background color. But I don't have
> a clue as to how to traverse back and get the corresponding column
> name and add that to the map.

**Just evaluate this XPath expression** (using your current context node that you found with this: `/DynamicReport/Columns/Column/FormattingInfo/Header/FontInfo`):

```
ancestor::Column[1]/ColumnName
```